Unable to login into SAP UFT using SAPGuiUtil.AutoLogon
The user name and password are getting entered but autologon is not happening.

SAP GUI is launched
User name and password is getting entered.

No message/error message is being displayed. It's stuck in SAP user credentials window.
Code:
SAPGuiUtil.AutoLogon "INT-S4","010", "username", "password", "EN"

For information, this code is working:
SAPGuiSession("Session").SAPGuiWindow("SAP").SAPGuiEdit("*User").Set "username"
SAPGuiSession("Session").SAPGuiWindow("SAP").SAPGuiEdit("*Password").Set "password"
SAPGuiSession("Session").SAPGuiWindow("SAP").SAPGuiEdit("*Password").SetFocus
SAPGuiSession("Session").SAPGuiWindow("SAP").SendKey ENTER

